# Looping over all models in r

Tags: r, time-series

## Scenario

I have some data and say, I want to implement 50 arima models and have their forecast. I am using forecast package to do this. Assume `result` is a matrix with dimensions 3(columns) and 50(rows) where first, second and third column containing values of p,d and q respectively. I would like to fit arima to all of them and get forecast for all of them. Following is my attempt:

```
y <- ts(rnorm(1000),start = 1850, frequency=1)
fit <- vector(mode="list", length=50)

for (j in 1:50){
   p[j]<- result[j,1]
   d[j]<- result[j,2]
   q[j]<- result[j,3]
    
   fit[[j]]<- arima(y, order=c(p[j],d[j],q[j]))
   fcasts<- forecast(fit[[j]], h=1)$mean
            
}
```

Which gives the following msg upon running:

```
Error in arima(y, order = c(p, d, q)) : 
  'order' must be a non-negative numeric vector of length 3
```

Any idea, how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you want `fit[j]<- arima(y, order=c(p[j],d[j],q[j]))`?

Comment: yes, that is what I want to do.

Comment: What is `class(fit)`?

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem like you are saving the forecasts. `fcasts` will be overwritten at every loop iteration. Maybe put them in a list? Initialize `fcast = list()` before the loop then put `fcasts[[j]] <- forecast(...)`.

Comment: @PierreLafortune. It showing up as ARIMA...

Comment: I'm sorry I should've said the class of fcasts, but Gregor explains it in the comment above. It should be a list

Comment: @Gregor. Your suggestion that fcast should be a list, does make sense, but indexing on fcast, is not possible, as I am carrying out the experiment as a sliding window and that will be used in looping over the data.

Comment: By the way, what does `result` contain? Valid balues for `p`, `q` and `d`?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi it is okay if fit is written over, the forecasts are saved

Comment: It looks like the user is attempting to save the forecasts not the models. Also we shouldn't edit the question as a way of correcting the method. It obscures questions vs answers.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi. Is it possible to use index like `fcasts[i[[j]]` in r?As mentioned in earlier comments, experiment is carried out as a sliding window, so I am already indexing `fcast[[i]]` to loop over the slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder whether this is what you really want to do:

```
y <- ts(rnorm(1000),start = 1850, frequency=1)
fcasts <- numeric(50)

for (j in 1:50){
   p <- result[j,1]
   d <- result[j,2]
   q <- result[j,3]

   fit <- arima(y, order=c(p, d, q))
   fcasts[j] <- forecast(fit, h=1)$mean  ## predicted mean of 1-day ahead forecast

}
```